# Is there a way to know what URLs are responding on Tomcat .war?

Tags: java, url, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have a java .war application and I deployed on Tomcat.

I looked for a way to know all the urls that respond under the "localhost:8080" path.
The solution may not be strictly linked with tomcat or java, it could be a browser option or other tools like a url mapper.

Do you have any suggestion?

UPDATE: the `/WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>notificationcardtrx-webapp</display-name>

<!-- Changing the default timeout so now the workstation use the same H2O timeout -->
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: You need to look at the `/WEB-INF/web.xml` file to see the mapping between URLs and servlets.

Comment: Can you look in the log file and see what URLs users are hitting?

Comment: When you say "URL mapper tool" do you mean a web crawler?

Comment: I updated the post with the /WEB-INF/web.xml but there is no response  (error 404 ) under "http://localhost:8080/notificationcardtrx-webapp/index.jsp"

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I can look in the logs of the application but it doesn't log anything beneath "the application is started" logs since I'm looking for a url to hit to test this application.
Yes, I mean something like a web crawler that could work on the localhost

Comment: To be able to start a web crawler you need to know at least one URL from the web app.  Can you visit the home page for the web app?

Comment: Did you post the entire web.xml file? There is no servlet definition. It means that there are only JSP pages (which is strange for a modern app).